# IP is not pinging by other system

Tags: networking

My system IP is not able to ping by other system in my company network but my system is in the network and able to ping other system in the network.

My system IP has a static IP and IP is pinging on by server.

Comment: You need to provide more information if you expect other to help. The question is also not clear: what do mean? Which machine is able (or not able) to ping what?

Comment: like there is A machine which IP is 192.168.1.97 not able to ping by B machine in the network and A machine is able to ping other System IP like 192.168.1.96 ,192.168.1.95 and so on

Comment: A machine IP is which is 192.168.1.97 is in the network and pinging by company server also and 192.168.1.97 is static IP not dynamic IP

Comment: What is the error message? Is it destination host not reachable?

Comment: now error is solved by changing the setting of Norton internet security

Comment: OK, a firewall was my next question... Is this now resolved for you?

Comment: yes problem is resolved by changing the settings of  Norton internet security firewall ny adding ICMP

Answer (score 1):

Answer is in original post's comments - it was the AV (Norton in this case).